# 2 counts in same query but different conditions

Tags: mysql, count, aggregate-functions, aggregate

This has been bothering me all day:

I want to do 2 counts in 1 table. The first counts how many shops in total, the second should count the shops in total where the price is lower than tsuppliers.lowestprice

So basically I want to combine the second query into the first:

```
SELECT tshops.shopID, tshops.OfficialName, tsuppliershopinfo.ContactName,   tsuppliershopinfo.ContactMail, Count(distinct tresults.pID) AS AantalVanpID
FROM (tsupplierproducts 
    INNER JOIN tresults ON tsupplierproducts.pID = tresults.pID)     
    INNER JOIN (tsuppliershopinfo INNER JOIN tshops ON tsuppliershopinfo.shopID = tshops.shopID) ON tresults.shopID = tsuppliershopinfo.shopID
WHERE (((tsupplierproducts.supplierID)=2)) AND tresults.starttime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY tshops.shopID, tshops.OfficialName, tsuppliershopinfo.ContactName, tsuppliershopinfo.ContactMail;
```

The second (notice that there's only one extra condition in the where-clause):

```
SELECT tresults.shopID, Count(distinct tresults.pID) AS AantalVanpID
FROM tsupplierproducts INNER JOIN tresults ON tsupplierproducts.pID = tresults.pID
WHERE (((tsupplierproducts.supplierID)=2) AND ((tresults.Price)<tsupplierproducts.LowestPrice)) AND tresults.starttime BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY tresults.shopID;
```

How can I combine the second query into the first query?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    tshops.shopID, 
    tshops.OfficialName, 
    tsuppliershopinfo.ContactName,   
    tsuppliershopinfo.ContactMail, 
    Count(distinct tresults.pID) AS AantalVanpID,
    Count(distinct 
        case when tresults.Price < tsupplierproducts.LowestPrice then tresult.pID end
        ) as AantalVanpID_2
FROM
    tsupplierproducts 
    INNER JOIN tresults ON tsupplierproducts.pID = tresults.pID   
    INNER JOIN tsuppliershopinfo ON tresults.shopID = tsuppliershopinfo.shopID
    INNER JOIN tshops ON tsuppliershopinfo.shopID = tshops.shopID
WHERE 
    tsupplierproducts.supplierID = 2
    AND 
    tresults.starttime BETWEEN 
        DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY 
    tshops.shopID, 
    tshops.OfficialName, 
    tsuppliershopinfo.ContactName, 
    tsuppliershopinfo.ContactMail
```

Comment: 1 word: awesome. Thanks! The query is running for almost a second. Do you advise to make a view from it to speed things up?

Comment: @kay10 A view will not affect performance. It will only make it easier to use the query in more than one context.

Comment: @kay10 If that running time is an issue than post another question including the result of the explain and the table's structures including indices

Comment: Thanks for the info. I managed to reduce the processing time significantly by joining a little different.